# implict functions and jacobians

Tags: calculus, implicit-differentiation

If $x+y^2=u, y+z^2=v, z+x^2=w$
find $\frac{\partial x}{\partial u}, \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial^2 u}, \frac{\partial^2 x}{\partial u \partial v}$

I've found out the first one using jacobians, but I have no idea of solving others. How should I approach?

Comment: Remember to use $LaTeX$! Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MathSE. Can you show your attempts for to solve this problem?

Comment: I used jacobian to compute ∂x/∂u, as considering x,y,z as independent variable